# Getting NullPointerException from message listener container, while staring spring boot application

Tags: spring-boot, redis, spring-data-redis, jedis, spring-session

I am getting following error with my Spring boot application:

```
Exception in thread "custom-message_listener-container-2" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryJedisPubSub.psubscribe(BinaryJedisPubSub.java:53)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisSubscription.doPsubscribe(JedisSubscription.java:59)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.util.AbstractSubscription.pSubscribe(AbstractSubscription.java:159)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.listener.RedisMessageListenerContainer$SubscriptionTask$PatternSubscriptionTask.run(RedisMessageListenerContainer.java:707)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

Redis pub/sub configuration for my application is as follows:

```
@Configuration
public class RedisPubSubConfiguration {

  @Bean("custom-message_listener-container")
  public RedisMessageListenerContainer messageListenerContainer(RedisConnectionFactory
                                                                      connectionFactory,
                                                                @Qualifier("topicAdapterPair")
                                                                    List<Pair
                                                                        <Topic,
                                                                            MessageListenerAdapter>>
                                                                         channelAdapterPairList) {
    RedisMessageListenerContainer container = new RedisMessageListenerContainer();
    for (Pair<Topic, MessageListenerAdapter> chanelAdapterPair : channelAdapterPairList) {
      container.addMessageListener(chanelAdapterPair.getValue(),
          chanelAdapterPair.getKey());
    }
    container.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    return container;
  }

  @Bean("redis-msg-listener-adptr")
  public MessageListenerAdapter ruleDBUpdateListenerAdapter(
      @Qualifier("message-listener")
          MessageListener listener) {
    return new MessageListenerAdapter(listener, REDIS_RECEIVER_METHOD_NAME);
  }

  @Bean("message-listener")
  public MessageListener listener(Manager manager) {
    return new Listener(manager);
  }

  @Bean("message-sender")
  public MessageSender ruleDBUpdateSender(RedisTemplate redisTemplate,
                                          @Value("${chnlTopicName}")
                                  String channelTopicName) {
    return new RefreshRuleEngineMessageSender(redisTemplate, channelTopicName);
  }

  @Bean
  @Qualifier("topicAdapterPair")
  public Pair<Topic, MessageListenerAdapter> getRuleEngineTopicListenerAdapterPair(
      @Value("${chnlTopicName}") String channelTopicName,
      @Qualifier("redis-msg-listener-adptr")
          MessageListenerAdapter messageListenerAdapter) {
    return Pair.of(new ChannelTopic(channelTopicName), messageListenerAdapter);
  }

  @Bean
  public KeyExpiredListener keyExpiredListener(
      @Qualifier("custom-message_listener-container")
      RedisMessageListenerContainer customMessageListenerContainer,
      KeyExpiryHandlerFactory keyExpiryHandlerFactory) {
    return new KeyExpiredListener(customMessageListenerContainer,
        keyExpiryHandlerFactory);
  }
}
```

pom.xml is as follows:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-session-data-redis</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
    <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Here jedis version is: 3.3.0 and spring-data-redis version is: 2.4.6

I am not able to understand, how should I fix this.